# Is this equivalence relation: $\{(1,2),(2,1),(1,1)\}$?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Let $S=\{1,2,3\}$ and $R=\{(1,2),(2,1),(1,1)\}$ Over $S, R$ does not have pairs like $(2,2),(3,3).$ Is it reflexive even though those elements in set $S$ are not used? But it is symmetric and transitive.

Comment: Partly correct: it's not reflexive. It's neither transitive, however.

Comment: It is not reflexive as $(2,2),(3,3)\not\in R$. It is not transitive because $(2,1), (1,2)\in R$ but $(2,2)\not\in R$. It *is* symmetric.

Comment: So for symmetric every element in S need not be present then why for reflexive we need every element, why it can be partially symmetric to be considered fully symmetric,but not for reflexive

Comment: Why need all pairs for reflexive only but not others

Answer (score 2):

Your relation $R$ is not an equivalence relation.

You have $(2,1)$ and $(1,2)$ but you do not have $(2,2)$ so it is not transitive.
You do not have  $(2,2)$ and $(3,3)$ so it is not reflexive.

Comment: Can it be partially transitive to be considered fully transitive, the rules for reflexive seem different ij that partialness is not allowed, but seems for transitiveness

Comment: {(1,2),(2,1),(1,1),(2,2)} is not reflexive?

Comment: If so then this should not be symmetric also as (1,3),(3,1) is missing in {(1,2),(2,1),(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)}

Comment: $R$ is symmetric as it is. You do not have to have all symmetric pairs in your relation.

Comment: But why is reflexive different then, wrt transitive,symmetric case

Comment: Please review the definitions to see the difference between transitive, symmetric, and reflexive.